# Ajax call with file upload and receive in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, upload

I want to upload a file through Ajax, and to receive in Spring MVC. Here is my client side code:

```
<form id="import-form" action="" method="post" enctpye="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="import" style="display:none;" />
</form>


$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options){
    var header = "<#if _csrf??>${_csrf.headerName}</#if>";
    var token = "<#if _csrf??>${_csrf.token}</#if>";
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});


$("#import").on("change", function(){

    var path = $(this).val();

    if(path == null || path == ""){
        alert("선택된 파일이 없습니다.");
        return;
    }

    var formTag = $("#import-form")[0];
    var formData = new FormData(formTag);
    formData.append("file", $(this)[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: managerRunner.importUrl,
        processData:null,
        data:formData,
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",

        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errThrown){
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the server side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/import-cheat", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<CheatImported> importCheats(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile cheats) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
        String path = getFileName(cheats);
        File file = new File(path);
        cheats.transferTo(file);

        try{
            return importService.importJsonFile(path);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            return null;
        }catch(ParseException e){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In this code, I do not care of the business logic *importService.importJsonFile()*.
I just want to upload a file successfully to the server. but there is an exception when trying to upload any file.

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:190) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

In this exception, it says it is not multipart request. So I added encoding type *multipart/form-data*.

```
$.ajax({
    url: managerRunner.importUrl,
    processData:null,
    data:formData,
    type:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:"multipart/form-data"
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errThrown);
    }
});
```

But even it throws the same error when trying to upload. Why does the exception come up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some extra configuration to your `ajax` call. In order for it to work, in my case I had to add `contentType: false`, `cache: false` and `processData: false`, in order to be able to send multipart files.

```
$.ajax({
    url: managerRunner.importUrl,
    data:formData,
    type:"post",

    // Tell jQuery not to process data or not to worry about content-type
    // You *must* include these options in order to send MultipartFile objects
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',

    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errThrown);
    }
});
```

Everything else is configured as intended, so it should work with those changes.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works! It seems like contentType to be *false*, not *null* as you mentioned.

Comment: I am glad I could help!